# Script for backup each DB on server but omit system databases

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, cron, backup

I have read a lot of post around this topic but I didn't found the one to fit my needs. So, basically I want to make two backups: one at mid day (12 PM) and the other at midnight (12 AM) for each database on a MySQL server but I want to leave out system databases: `mysql` and `information_schema` (as far as I know is there is another one please let me know). After read a lot of topics I come with this bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
now="$(date +'%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')"
filename="db_backup_$now".gz
backupfolder="/home/backups"
fullpathbackupfile="$backupfolder/$filename"
logfile="$backupfolder/"backup_log_"$(date +'%Y_%m')".txt
echo "mysqldump started at $(date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')" >> "$logfile"
mysqldump --user=userbackup --password=***** --default-character-set=utf8 database | gzip > "$fullpathbackupfile"
echo "mysqldump finished at $(date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')" >> "$logfile"
find "$backupfolder" -name db_backup_* -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
echo "old files deleted" >> "$logfile"
echo "operation finished at $(date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')" >> "$logfile"
echo "*****************" >> "$logfile"
exit 0
```

This script made a backup for database `database` and keep 7 last `.tar.gz` files. Can any help me to improve this script so I can backup each database other than system ones and keep 7 last copies for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using `PostgreSQL`, and I do something that looks really close to what you want to achieve, so this is my backup script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Editable parameters:
#
## Filesystem Location to place backups.
BACKUP_DIR="/path/to/backup/folder"
## The user used to connect to postgres instance
USER="postgres"
PWD="pwd_in_plaintext_is_not_a_"
## Just the date string that will be appended to the backup files name
BACKUP_DATE="$(date +'%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')"
## Numbers of days you want to keep copie of your databases
NUMBER_OF_DAYS=7
## Uncomment following line if you want to overwrite the whole folder each time
#rm -rf ${BACKUP_DIR}/backupFulldb-*
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# don't change anything below this line

# Vacumm al databases before begin to backup
vacuumdb --all -U ${USER}

DATABASES=`psql -U ${USER} -l -t | cut -d'|' -f1 | sed -e 's/ //g' -e '/^$/d'`
for i in ${DATABASES}; do
  if [ "$i" != "template0" ] && [ "$i" != "template1" ]; then
    echo Dumping $i to ${BACKUP_DIR}
    pg_dump -U ${USER} --column-inserts $i | gzip -c >  ${BACKUP_DIR}/backupFulldb-$i-${BACKUP_DATE}.out.gz
  fi
done
find ${BACKUP_DIR} -type f -prune -mtime +${NUMBER_OF_DAYS} -exec rm -f {} \;
```

You just need a query that list all dbs in your mysql instance, and replace it for the `DATABASES` array. Reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843896/store-query-in-array-in-bash#13844224) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499372/get-list-of-mysql-databases-and-server-version#3499599), I assume you could eg. do as follow:

```
while read line
do 
    DATABASES+=("$line")
done < <(mysql -u${USER} -p${PWD} INFORMATION_SCHEMA -e "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA")
```

And sure, fix the dbs names you want to exclude:

```
if [ "$i" != "mysql" ] && [ "$i" != "information_schema" ]; then
```